# Handling and printing data in CSV files

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, csv

I have two CSV files. The first column in both files is a timestamp but all the other columns contain different data. Some of these timestamps overlap but occur in different rows.
I want to create a new file which contains all the overlapping timestamps, along with the relevant data from both files.

For example:

File 1:

```
['1', 'John', 'Doe'] 
['2', 'Jane', 'Deer']
['3', 'Horror', 'Movie']
```

File 2:

```
['2', 'Mac']
['3', 'bro']
['4', 'come']
['1', '@mebro']
```

Output File:

```
['1', 'John', 'Doe', '@mebro']
['2', 'Jane', 'Deer', 'Mac']
['3', 'Horror', 'Movie', 'bro']
```

This is the code I have so far:

```
Outfile = []

for row in file2:
Outfile.append(tuple(row))

if len(file1) >= len(file2):
    for n in xrange(1,len(file2)):
        if file1[0][n] == file2[0][:]:
            Outfile.append(file1[1:8][n])

if len(file2) >= len(file1):
    for n in xrange(1,len(file1)):
        if file1[0][n] == file2[0][:]:
            Outfile.append(file1[1:8][n])

resultFile = open("resultFile.csv","wb")
wr = csv.writer(Outfile, dialect= "excel")
wr.writerows(Outfile)
```

Comment: I assume that the current approach is giving you errors of some kind, or is it just producing unexpected output? If I understand the way you're storing data in the lists, `if file1[0][n]` will be just looking element-by-element through a single row, and not going through all the rows of data?

Comment: @roganjosh The way I understand it, file1[0][n] refers to the nth row in the 0th column. So you are correct in assuming that it looks element-by-element, but it should in theory be looking through 'n' rows.

Comment: @mds has given you an answer that probably solves your problem assuming that when you say "overlapping timestamps" that they are actually exactly-matching integers as in your example. However, for your example, if your list structure is actually a nested list `[['1', 'joe], ['2', 'Jane']]` etc. then you would use `file1[n][0]` to take the first value in the n'th row for comparison. I think if you put print statements under each `if` to show if it works, nothing would print and then you'll get an error based on index being out of range?

Comment: You were bang on @roganjosh. Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: No problem :) Please feel free to up-vote the answers if they were helpful. Though mds should really get the tick because my answer was more an aside about indices and leaves some points outstanding such as items in list1 will still be in the final list even if there was no corresponding duplicate timestamp in list2 etc. If this is important then I can modify my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use pandas library.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv("path to file 1")
df2 = pd.read_csv("path to file 2")

result = merge(df1, df2, on='First column', sort=True)
result.to_csv("path to result file")
```

merge will join the two dataframes with specified column.

[More Information](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-joining-merging)

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by mds is much more efficient and I only give this as supplementary information because there are a number of fundamental issues with the way you are trying to use list indices. This code will give the output list you are looking for and might illustrate better how they work (with the addition of 'example' in file2 to show how it would add additional elements).

```
list1 = [['1', 'John', 'Doe'], 
        ['2', 'Jane', 'Deer'],
        ['3', 'Horror', 'Movie']]

list2 = [['2', 'Mac', 'example'],
        ['3', 'bro'],
        ['4', 'come'],
        ['1', '@mebro']]

for x in range(len(list1)):
    print "List1 timestamp for consideration: " + str(list1[x][0])
    for y in range(len(list2)):
        print "Compared to list2 timestamp: " + str(list2[y][0])
        if list1[x][0] == list2[y][0]:
            print "Match"
            for z in range(1,len(list2[y])):
                list1[x].append(list2[y][z])
```

Your printed output from this is:

```
List1 timestamp for consideration: 1
Compared to list2 timestamp: 2
Compared to list2 timestamp: 3
Compared to list2 timestamp: 4
Compared to list2 timestamp: 1
Match
List1 timestamp for consideration: 2
Compared to list2 timestamp: 2
Match
Compared to list2 timestamp: 3
Compared to list2 timestamp: 4
Compared to list2 timestamp: 1
List1 timestamp for consideration: 3
Compared to list2 timestamp: 2
Compared to list2 timestamp: 3
Match
Compared to list2 timestamp: 4
Compared to list2 timestamp: 1
```

With list1 then looking like:

```
list 1 = [['1', 'John', 'Doe', '@mebro'],
 ['2', 'Jane', 'Deer', 'Mac', 'example'],
 ['3', 'Horror', 'Movie', 'bro']]
```